# Dask.distributed kill workers Everytime I run

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have been having problems with dask.distributed. Everytime I run it, it always has memory issues and kills my workers, when running on my laptop. I have a laptop with 16GB and run 4 workers, when I try to run a computation it seems to straight away kill workers. Ive tried limiting the ram to 3.5 GB but that doesnt work. My chunk sizes are around 200MB. I am using a zarr file with a 3diim array stored. So I don't understand why I have this issue. I had it working a few months ago and took some time away from it when this problem occurred. I tired a smaller overall data set and the same issue occurs. Any thoughts?
When I run this outside of distributed I don't have the same issue?

Happy to show error reports and a minimum example if anyone has idea's?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at logs.  `KilledWorker` errors can occur for many reasons.  For example you might not have the same version of Dask everywhere or you might be launching workers someplace where they can't connect.

Comment: Looking at the logs it just says that the workers were killed because of exceeding memory. Do you mean a version of dask in my virtual enviroment or a different one? Whats the best way to fix all of that without ruining my dependencies? I have dask workign on my data set without distributed so happy to just leave it alone but also would love to get distributed up an running too.

Comment: Given that you're exceeding memory I would next look into why.  Using the dashboard is probably a good move here.  It might help you understand what is happening.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_GqzcuGLCY&t=2s

Comment: So after working on this and having got some advice from @MRocklin  on github it looks like it was incompatible libraries with dask. Specifically scikit image and ndimage. When I ran median filter with a dask client on a local machine I went from a total time of 21secs but with distributed it ran in 279ms for a 19GB file with a 16GB ram laptop. Ive raised a feature request on dask_image to try to provide further info on their wrapper util. This seems to be the big difference between the ndimage.filter in scipy and the one that works in dask_image. Thanks and appreciate you advice.